# Automorphisms of punctured plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

It is well known that set of automorphisms (bijective, conformal self maps) of

- $\Bbb{C}_{\infty}$ is $\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d},\,\,\,ad-bc\not=0$ (Möbius transformations),
- $\Bbb{C}$ is $az+b,\,\,\, a\not=0$ (scaling+rotating+translating),
- $\Bbb{H}$ is $\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d},\,\,\,ad-bc\not=0$ with $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}$,
- $\Bbb{D}$ is $e^{i\theta}\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z},\,\,\,|a|\lt1,\,\,\,\theta\in\Bbb{R}$,
- $\text{Ann}(0,r_1,r_2)$ is $e^{i\theta}z,\,\,\,\theta\in\Bbb{R}.$

> Here I am trying to figure-out the automorphisms of punctured plane $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}.$ My guess is it is the collection of functions of the form $az+\dfrac{b}{z},$ where $a,b$ are any two complex numbers with $|a|^2+|b|^2\not=0.$ Is it correct? If it is so, how can I prove this rigorously?

Comment: These are the automorphisms of the Riemann sphere which fix setwise the two point $\{0, \infty\}$. Let $f$ be such an automorphism.  If $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\infty)=\infty$, then $f(z)=az$ for some non-zero complex number $a$. If $f(0)=\infty$ and $f(\infty)=0$, then $f(z)=b/z$ for some non-zero complex number $b$.

Comment: Also, note that $a=b=1$ doesn't work in your guess, since the image of $i$ would be $0$.

Comment: @SteveD: Oh... I see. In fact those functions are not injective.

Comment: You must have $\lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2 \neq 0$ _and_ $ab = 0$. And for the annuli, don't forget $z \mapsto e^{i\theta} \frac{r_1r_2}{z}$ if $0 < r_1 < r_2 < \infty$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is generated by linear maps $z\mapsto az$ (with $a\ne 0$) and inversion $z\mapsto 1/z$. So, every element of the group can be written as $z\mapsto az^{\pm 1}$.

Indeed, suppose $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Since $f$ is injective, $0$ cannot be a point of essential singularity (recall Picard's theorem), so it's either a pole or removable singularity. By replacing $f$ with $1/f$ if necessary, we can assume $0$ is removable. Then $f$ extends to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$, so $f(z)=az+b$. And since it fixes $0$, $b=0$.

Comment: I would like to know how Picard theorem can be used. $f$ can omit a single value, seems no contradiction because the range is $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\0\}$. "0" is the value omitted. By the way, why we can ensure the pole is of order 1?

Comment: @Leonardo I think the Great Picard theorem is being used as opposed to the Little Picard theorem. Great Picard will give the desired implication.

Comment: This can be done without the weight of Picard. Suppose $0$ is an essential singularity and $f(w)=1$ for exactly one $w$.  The open mapping theorem tells us $B\big(1,\epsilon\big) \subseteq f\Big(B\big(w,\frac{|w|}{2}\big)\Big)$ for $\epsilon \gt 0$ small enough. But  Casorati–Weierstrass tells us there is a sequence $z_k\to 0$ where $f\big(z_k\big) \in B\big(1,\epsilon\big)$ for all $k$ large enough, contradicting injectivity.