# What are the holomorphic injections from $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What are the holomorphic injections from $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$? I mean from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ , we know it’s the functions like $az + b$, a different of $0$. But I don’t know for $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$. Thank you

Comment: Such a function has a pole or a removable singularity at $z=0$, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2397402/42969.

Comment: Examples are $az$ and $a/z$.  Are there others?