# Automorphism of punctured plane must fix 0.

Tags: complex-analysis

In [this accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397236/automorphisms-of-punctured-plane) to the question of finding the automorphisms $f$ of the punctured plane , it is stated that by taking $1/f$ if necessary, we can assume that $0$ is a removable singularity. We then assume that the automorphism fixes $0$. Why is that?

My thinking is that if $f(z)=\alpha z +\beta$, then $f(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\beta\}$ and hence if $\beta\neq 0$, $f$ is not an automorphism. Is this correct?

Comment: You have misquoted that answer. Consider e.g. $f(z) = 1/z$. Clearly an automorphism of the punctured plane, but is not even defined at 0. The answer actually gives a pretty clear explanation of it, which part do you not understand?

Comment: Fair point, I have updated the question to be more precise.

Comment: I hope you don't find this pedantic, but the answer does still give you an answer to the part you quoted. It says that by [Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem#The_theorems), 0 is not an essential singularity. Therefore it's either a pole or a removable singularity. Which part of that isn't clear?

Comment: I added a comment in the linked answer as I thought Picard was overkill.

Comment: @preferred_anon That is not my question. My question is why $f(0)=0$ with $f$ having a removable singularity at zero.

Comment: @Dispersion My previous comment explains why 0 is a removable singularity (which is what you asked). Given 0 is a removable singularity, wanting to prove $f(0)=0$: $f$ extends to an entire function, and so does the inverse of $f$. The answer claims $f$ extends to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ (which would immediately imply $f(0)=0$, because every other point is taken). It seems obvious to try and prove that the extensions of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are still inverse pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the answerer immediately concluded that $f$ was an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. It's certainly obvious that $f$ is entire, but I had to do some work to prove $f(0) = 0$.

1. From that answer, if $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, then 0 is either a pole or removable singularity of $f$.
2. Let $g$ be whichever of $f$ and $1/f$ has a removable singularity. $g$ is still an automorphism of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.
3. Consider $g(1/z)$, which is also an automorphism of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. For the same reason as before, it must not have an essential singularity. So $h$ which is defined as either $z \to g(1/z)$ or $z \to 1/g(1/z)$ has a removable singularity at 0 too.
4. But note that $g(0)$ or $1/g(0)$ is a limiting value of $h(z)$ as $z \to \infty$. If $g(0) \ne 0$, then $h$ is bounded, and entire, hence constant. This is a contradiction.

The intuitive picture is much clearer: Since $f$ is an automorphism on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, it has no essential singularities. So $0$ and $\infty$ are either poles or zeroes, and hence $f$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. If $(0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ or $(\infty, 0)$, then $f$ is an automorphism. If they both go to zero or $\infty$ you break Liouville.